# Error launching AVD from Android Studio

Tags: android, windows

I have a pop up message that display that Hax is not installed but when I go the sdk manager it is installed. Please help !

Comment: the sdk does not actually istall HAXM, it only downloads the installer to the extras directory

Comment: how do i get it to work ?

Answer (score 1):

You shoud to go to

```
%YOUR_SDK_LOCATION%\android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

and execute installer, after that you can use x86 based images to emulation

Comment: I cant seem to be able to find that

Comment: @user2840592 irotsoma has a good solution for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/27871018/1897374 - just download and install HAXM from the Intel web site

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I had to manually install from Intel:  https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager